# What is the best sorting methods?

Tags: sorting

I need more  Sorting algorithms instead of these :
Insertion
Selection
Bubble
Shell
Merge
Heap
Quick
Radix
**can anyone help ?**

Answer (score 0):

- **Quick sort is best sorting algorithms**: QuickSort is a Divide and Conquer algorithm.  It picks an element as pivot, movies smaller than pivot to left, moves larger than pivot to right.
- Like QuickSort, Merge Sort is a Divide and Conquer algorithm. recursively divided in two halves till the size becomes 1, merge them back together sorted.
- Bubble Sort is the simplest sorting algorithm.  It is not used in the real world, since it is not very efficient. Elements bubble to front and back.
- Selection sort algorithm sorts an array by repeatedly finding the minimum/maximum element. This algorithm maintains two subarrays, one subarray contains selected list which is sorted and other subarray contains remaining items which are not sorted.

Look at this links

> http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/
>   https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/ComparisonSort.html